# Python Web3: How to get an address from a private key?

Tags: python, web3py

I want to get the public address from a private key, which I know is feasible. How could I do so in using Python web3 library?

My attempt so far:

`account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(str(PrivateKey))`

`print(account.address)`

`Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'privateKeyToAccount'`

Comment: What version of web3 did you install (`pip show web3`)? I tried running your code and it gives a different output. In version __5.28.0__ there is no `web3.eth.accounts`... Are you running a different version?

Comment: Yes, 5.28.0, and it is possible on another as that to receive the address?

Comment: I think to get the acocunt you should call [from_key](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.from_key) `web3.eth.Account.from_key(str(PrivateKey))` and then you should be able to get `account.address`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Eth' object has no attribute 'Account'

Comment: That is your __web3__? `import web3`?

Comment: I believe you might have done something like `web3 = web3.Web3()`... Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

You should create the account using [from_key](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.from_key)

```py
from web3 import Web3
# Connect to Ganache, make sure ganache is running
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"))

#Check Connection
t=w3.isConnected()
print(t)

# Get private key 
Private_key_Wallet_2 =  '0xc76...........8......24'

# Create a signer wallet
PA=w3.eth.account.from_key(Private_key_Wallet_2)

# Get public address from a signer wallet
Public_Address=PA.address
print(Public_Address)
```

Comment: Pleas use english only on StackOverflow

Comment: Did it work, but is there a way to find out if the private key is valid? Or that the console did not write an error if the private key is invalid.

Comment: If it worked please mark the answer as correct. I am not sure about verifying the key but I would suggest opening a new question, probably someone will know the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt you used this

```
account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(str(PrivateKey))
```

this calls (eth.accounts)
thats basically the list of accounts user has access to
What you need to use is eth.account

```
account = web3.eth.account.from_key(str(PrivateKey))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues, but I fixed this
I got the address from the Public Key
Firstly, I got the public key from private key
And then I got the address from the public key
Flow this,

```
def createPublicKey(private_key_hex):
    private_key_bytes = bytes.fromhex(private_key_hex)

    # generate the ECDSA curve object
    curve = ecdsa.curves.SECP256k1

    # get the public key point from the private key bytes
    private_key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key_bytes, curve=curve)
    public_key_point = private_key.verifying_key.pubkey.point

    # convert the public key point to bytes
    public_key_bytes = public_key_point.to_bytes()

    # print the public key bytes
    return public_key_bytes.hex()
```

Second,
you can get the address with public key like following:
(https://gist.github.com/VictorNS69/3708d6c20a66dcf9eec235d46e02bc76)

```
import codecs
from Crypto.Hash import keccak

# An example of public key is:a33e56a80b9dc83a4456265d877c0765cea76146e625572fc679804f8867222ca3c816433a9b6e6690b0b8e919ffa874982706e812314aae09d85fc62fc4fa3c
public_key_bytes = codecs.decode("your public key here", "hex")
keccak_hash = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
keccak_hash.update(public_key_bytes)
keccak_digest = keccak_hash.hexdigest()
wallet_len = 40
wallet = "0x" + keccak_digest[-wallet_len:]

print("address", wallet)
```

Hope this will be helpful for everyone.

Answer (score -1):

`web3.eth.accounts` is a list and the syntax you're applying here implies you're working with something different. [Doc](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.accounts)
I suppose you looked in the [web3 js documentations here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount) which, in fact, does have said method and syntax combination.